# azure video plugin sharing on video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, media-player, azure-media-services

I am using azure plugin to play videos on site. I want to share video on social sites using sharing functionality.

[Azure video player with sharing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONTUL.png)

I have done below code for integrating azure plugin to my application.

```
<html>
        <head>
            <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.3/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
            <script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.3/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="padding-top:10px"><video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0"></video>   </div>
        </body>

        </html>

    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function () {    
                var myOptions = {
                    "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
                    controls: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    width: "640",
                    height: "400",
                }
                myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
                myPlayer.src([
                        {
                            "src": "//amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest",
                            "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
                        }
                ]);
            });
    </script>
```

I want share functionality(share icons) on top right corner of video not in default controls.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

As Azure Media Service team has provided a javascript plun to share the asset to social.

You can add a javascript lib script and a css file in your page,

```
<link href="amp-share.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="amp-share.js"></script>
```

and add an event listener of your media server player instance in your script.

```
myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions,function(){
                    this.addEventListener(amp.eventName.loadedmetadata, function () {
                        var shareOption = new Amp.Plugin.Share.ShareOptions;
                        shareOption.socialShare.shareIcons.push(Amp.Plugin.Share.SocialShareIcon.getPredefinedShareIcon(0 /* Facebook */));
                        shareOption.socialShare.shareIcons.push(Amp.Plugin.Share.SocialShareIcon.getPredefinedShareIcon(1 /* Twitter */));
                        shareOption.socialShare.shareIcons.push(Amp.Plugin.Share.SocialShareIcon.getPredefinedShareIcon(2 /* LinkedIn */));
                        shareOption.socialShare.shareIcons.push(Amp.Plugin.Share.SocialShareIcon.getPredefinedShareIcon(3 /* Mail */));
                        this.share(shareOption);/* plugin initialization*/
                    });
                });
```

Please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-javascript-azure-media-player-social-share-plugin for the whole project.

Comment: This code shows share buttons as a default controls. And i want share buttons  on top right corner of video. I tried this code but output is not as i want.

Answer (score 1):

the plugin you're looking at right now, as you have noticed, adds a share button to the control bar. If this is not the output you are looking for, you can fork the plugin and remove the code that creates the button in the control bar.

If you want to add a button in the top right hand corner, you'll have to overlay an html element and set it's inner html to be the icon you'd like. 
(Video JS has a similar plugin that does that here: https://github.com/jmccraw/videojs-socialShare/)

Then, give it an event listener on click and launch the share menu overlay that is already written in the GitHub.

if you have more questions about this, feel free to email ampinfo@microsoft.com